# vpn programmatically android

Tags: android, http, proxy, header, vpn

I want to create android app that intercept all http requests of the android device
and it applies some modifciations to the http requests header.

is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Android SDK has built in support for making your own VPNs, check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html to see if it is really possible. Your best bet would be to configure the VPN and then, on the server side do the modifications there.